# How to prove logical truth in predicate calculus?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Next week I have a final exam in math logic, then I'm trying to solve a sample exam but I'm having a difficulty.

I have a formula under predicate calculus, and I have to prove that it's a logical truth.

> 12 . (8%) Let $P, R, Q$ be a predicate signs. Prove that:
>
> $\exists x (R(x)\lor P(x)) \to (\forall y \lnot R(y) \to (\exists x Q(x) \to \forall x \lnot P(x))) $

I thought to solve it using a truth table, but I've noticed that there are $5$ predicates which are $2^5 = 32$ rows and I don't think that it's the right way.

How can I prove that this predicate is logical truth?

Please help me. thanks in advance!

Comment: Using as template a similar thing in your book/notes. I would let $M$ be a structure for the language. We want to prove that a certain implication holds. To verify it, all we need to check is situations where the first part is true. So suppose there really is an $a\in M$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you please extend your answer?

Comment: So there is an $a\in M$ such that $R^\ast(a)$ is true in $M$ or $P^\ast(a)$ is true in $M$, were we use $F^\ast$ to mean the interpretation of $F$ in $M$. Suppose first that $R^\ast(a)$ is true in $M$, Then $\dots$.

Comment: There are only 3 predicates and have you not learned a way to prove theorems?

Comment: The given formula is false: for a countermodel, take a one-element set whose unique element satisfies $P$ and $Q$ but not $R$.

Comment: By thinking about the supposed sturcture $M$ you can see that everything is fine if there is an $a$ such that $R^\ast(a)$.  For then the first part of the consequent is automatically false, so the consequent is true. But what about if $R$ fails everywhere. Now see whether you can build a model in which the sentence is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to prove that the given implication necessarily holds. To verify the formula, we need to check only the situations where the antecedent is true. So we suppose there exists an $x:= a \in U$ such that either $R(a)$ or $P(a)$.

As Zhen Lin suggests, we see that the statement is false when $P(a) \land Q(a) \land \lnot R(a)$ holds, together with a universe U in which for all $\forall x \in U, \lnot R(x)$, i.e., $\lnot \exists x (R(x))$,  where $U$ is the universe over which we are quantifying. Then we have a true antecedent but a false conclusion, and hence, a situation in which the implication is false.

Hence the statement fails to be a logical truth.

Comment: Always so excellent with these +1

Answer (score 0):

> $\exists x (R(x)\lor P(x)) \to (\forall y \lnot R(y) \to (\exists x Q(x) \to \forall x \lnot P(x))) $

Another perhaps more intuitive approach to show this statement must be false:

Suppose that $\exists x (R(x)\lor P(x))$. Specify $R(a) \lor P(a)$

Suppose further that $\forall y \lnot R(y)$. Since $R(a) \lor P(a)$, we must then have $P(a)$.

Suppose further that $\exists x Q(x)$. Since $P(a)$, we *cannot* then have $\forall x \lnot P(x)$.